# HTML form submit issues with GoDaddy gdform.php

Tags: html, forms

I apologize ahead of time if this is a newbie question, but I can't seem to find my answer anywhere.

So I am having a really tricky time getting my form to display its submitted content when it is routed to my email.

I am receiving an email upon submission, but it is not showing any of the content from my form.

I am using GoDaddy Linux hosting with gdform.php

I have attempted both enctypes text/plain & application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

my form code is as follows:

```
<form id="myform" class="col col_8" action="gdform.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Submission" />
    <fieldset class="s_column"> 
        <legend></legend>
        <div>
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" required="required" class="box_shadow" title="Don't worry, I don't share" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">phone</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" required="required" class="box_shadow" title="In case of emergency" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" required="required" class="box_shadow" title="What shall I call you, when I call you?" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="url">url</label>
            <input type="url" id="url" class="box_shadow" title="If no url, share one that inspires you!" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">Budget</label>
            <input type="number" id="Budget" class="box_shadow" title="Dollars and Sense" />
        </div>
        <div class="textarea">
            <label for="textarea">Message</label>
            <textarea class="box_shadow" title="Whats on your mind?"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit form &rarr;" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can view the form page at rawdesigns.net/contact.html

Comment: We'll need to see the relevant PHP code that sends the email.

Answer (score 1):

They are not working because your dont have any of them named. Also you have the type wrong the type should always be text.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
```

The only input that would be different is a password then your type would be type="password". When your are submitting form data you always have to give it a name unless you are using jquery or javascript. the code above would then submit the value typed in using the identifier name. And in php you would get the info like so:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Just make sure you name all of the fields and change the type to text and it should work fine.

Comment: Actually, `email`, `tel`, `url`, and `number` are all valid input names if you are using HTML5 - and they provide extra validation in modern browsers.

Comment: I am gonna have to look into that. Wow you learn something new every day.

Comment: "names" should be "types" - but you got the gist :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!

Adding the names to my form fields did the trick!

As well, I removed godaddy's crappy gdform.php and supplemented a simple PHP script I found and customized to my form.